Decrypt Audio enc to ogg, node and typescript
I'm working on a WhatsApp chatbot with Node and TypeScript. Everything works fine, but when I send an audio it comes encrypted in an enc format. The message brings more information like url, mimetype, mediaKey, etc... that will be to decrypt it and be able to access the audio that I have sent through the bot. The thing is that I have created three methods, a main one, one that is in charge of downloading the encrypted file and another one that describes it. But when I run it, the ogg file is corrupted.
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import MessageBotAudio from '../interfaces/messageBotAudio';

export async function downloadFile(url: string, filePath: string): Promise<string> {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to fetch ${url}: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const buffer = await response.buffer();
    await fs.writeFile(filePath, buffer);

    return filePath;
}

const decryptAudio = async (encryptedFilePath: string, decryptedFilePath: string, audioMessage: MessageBotAudio) => {
    try {
        const key = Buffer.from(audioMessage.audioMessage.mediaKey);
        const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);

        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv);
        const encryptedData = await fs.readFile(encryptedFilePath);
        const decryptedData = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encryptedData), decipher.final()]);

        await fs.writeFile(decryptedFilePath, decryptedData);

        return decryptedFilePath;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error al desencriptar el archivo:', error.message);
        throw error;
    }
};


export const handleAudioMessage = async (audioMessage: MessageBotAudio): Promise<string> => {
    const encryptedFilePath = './audio.enc';
    const decryptedFilePath = './audio.ogg';


    await downloadFile(audioMessage.audioMessage.url, encryptedFilePath);

    return await decryptAudio(encryptedFilePath, decryptedFilePath, audioMessage);
};

This is the code I have implemented and it works but it must not decrypt the files properly or something because I get corrupted files.
This is the message I receive from the bot
export default interface MessageBotAudio {
    audioMessage: AudioMessage;
    messageContextInfo: MessageContextInfo;
}

interface AudioMessage {
    url: string;
    mimetype: string;
    fileEncSha256: Uint8Array;
    fileLength: Long;
    seconds: number;
    ptt: boolean;
    mediaKey: Uint8Array;
    fileSha256: Uint8Array;
    directPath: string;
    mediaKeyTimestamp: Long;
    streamingSidecar: Uint8Array;
    waveform: Uint8Array;
}

interface MessageContextInfo {
    deviceListMetadata: DeviceListMetadata;
    deviceListMetadataVersion: number;
}

interface DeviceListMetadata {
    senderKeyIndexes: number[];
    recipientKeyIndexes: number[];
    senderKeyHash: Uint8Array[];
    recipientKeyHash: Uint8Array[];
    recipientTimestamp: Long[];
}

message_from_bot
And the code works, I send a message and it creates the two audios but they are corrupted.
files
corrupted_example

To resolve this issue I used WhatsApp-Media-Decrypt to decrypt the audio message, first you need to make the project to a executable file, and then use it.


/**
 * Se encarga de desencriptar un archivo de WhatsApp a través de la ejecución de un binario.
 * Se necesita el archivo encriptado, la ruta de salida, el tipo de medio y la clave de encriptación.
 * @param encFilePath ruta del archivo encriptado
 * @param outputFilePath ruta del archivo de salida
 * @param mediaType parámetro de tipo de medio
 * @param hexMediaKey clave de encriptación
 * @returns void
 */
export async function decryptMedia(encFilePath: string, outputFilePath: string, mediaType: number, hexMediaKey: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const { stdout, stderr } = await execFileAsync('./bin/whatsapp-media-decrypt', [
            '-o', outputFilePath,
            '-t', mediaType.toString(),
            encFilePath,
            hexMediaKey
        ]);

        if (stderr) {
            console.error('Error:', stderr);
            return;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Execution error:', error);
    }
}



